# Cannot install mailman with Puppet if maillist is also specified

Tags: puppet

```
package { 'mailman':
  ensure  => installed,
  require => Package['exim4'],
}
maillist { 'mailman':
  ensure      => 'present',
  admin       => $admin,
  description => 'Site list',
  password    => $master_password,
  require     => Package['mailman'],
}
```

If package "mailman" has not been installed, then puppet complains that it "Could not find a default provider for maillist". It seems it considers this to be an error in the manifest, because it aborts entirely and does not apply any configuration. As a result, it does not process the "package { 'mailman': ... }" directive, which means it does not install mailman. I need to comment out the maillist directive, then apply the configuration so that mailman is installed, then uncomment and reapply. But this is not satisfactory.

How can I do it in a better way?

Comment: What happens if you specify `provider => mailman` in mailist {} define?

Comment: Again, it doesn't work. I don't remember if the error message is exactly the same, however it can't find the mailman provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a fix in Puppet 2.7.8, for issue [#6907](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/6907) that enables a provider to be installed or synchronised during the run that it's being used in (subject to normal dependencies being specified).  See the [2.7.8 release notes](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/1/wiki/Release_Notes#Allow-providers-to-be-used-in-the-run-they-become-suitable) too.

You should find it fixes this case, allowing you to install the Mailman dependency for the maillist provider during the same run.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using 2.7.6 from squeeze-backports. (testing has 2.7.11 - I wonder if backports get updated.)

Answer (score 2):

One simple thing you could do is create a [custom fact](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_facts.html) that will report if mailman is installed on your system.  Just have the fact return true or false depending on the presence of the binary.

Then just add a conditional to your your manifest.

```
if (true = $gotmailman)
{
    maillist { 'mailman':
      ensure      => 'present',
      admin       => $admin,
      description => 'Site list',
      password    => $master_password,
      require     => Package['mailman'],
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you meant to have the "maillist" inside the "if", not the "package"?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks, this is a useful tip until I upgrade Puppet to 2.7.8 or later.